# Convert single text string into rows and columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a single text string with words separated by spaces, e.g. "blah cah nah....".

Say I would like to split this into n words by m columns, i.e., a word per cell. I know I can use text to columns to get the m columns, but how about the rows? I could hash together a cut and paste macro that'd do it, but are there any built in functions that could do the same thing?

Comment: I don't follow - what do you mean by m columns?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work:

1. Use text to columns to get everything in a single row.
2. Use transpose to change the single row into a single column.

   - See [Switch (transpose) columns and rows](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Switch-transpose-columns-and-rows-ed1215f5-59af-47e6-953b-0b513b094dc2)
3. Use transpose again to split the single column into multiple columns.

   - See [How do I transpose data in columns to rows?](https://superuser.com/questions/398257/how-do-i-transpose-data-in-columns-to-rows)