# How to transpose two cells data at a time from 2 cells to multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have Excel data in the below format:

```
Excel Std Row: A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J
 1st Row Data: 1    1    2    2    4    4    5    5    6    6
```

Now I need output as below:

```
A  B
1  1
2  2
4  4 
5  5
6  6
```

Can someone tell me how to use the "Transpose" function in this case?

Note: A, B, C, are standard Excel column alphabets & not user defined column.

Answer (score 0):

How do I transpose two cells data at a time from 2 cells to multiple rows

1. Use transpose to change the single row into a single column.

   - See [Switch (transpose) columns and rows](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Switch-transpose-columns-and-rows-ed1215f5-59af-47e6-953b-0b513b094dc2)
2. Use transpose again to split the single column into multiple columns.

   - See [How do I transpose data in columns to rows?](https://superuser.com/questions/398257/how-do-i-transpose-data-in-columns-to-rows)