# How to transpose repeating groups in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How would I transpose repeating rows and columns in Excel.  For example how would I transpose the repeating pattern of rows (Tan color) to repeating columns (Purple). Would I need to do this in VBA and are there some built in functions.  Actual worksheet has 8,000 rows which need to be transposed.

[image]

Comment: [How do I transpose data in columns to rows?](http://superuser.com/q/398257) might get you started.

Comment: Does the original data have a constant number of rows in each group? In that case, the `OFFSET` function, using (pseudocode): row = fixed_heigth * target_column and column = row modulo fixed_height. Let us know what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @agtoever would you please elaborate your comment as an answer? I'm also interested in the solution. From what I understand, yes, it does have a constant number of rows in each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one's for you, @LucasPottersky

If you have the tan data and you want to transpose it to the purple data, here is a formula by which you may do that. **This formula only works because the specific example in OP's question has repeating data. If your data does not repeat, this will not work for you.**

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$16,MATCH(G$1,$G$1:$K$1,0),MATCH($F2,$B$1:$D$1,0))
```

`$B$2:$D$16` is the range containing all the tan data *but not the headers*.

`MATCH(G$1,$G$1:$K$1,0)` returns the row we want

`MATCH($F2,$B$1:$D$1,0)` returns the column we want

You'll have to manually copy / paste the headers and the formula for as many rows as is needed.